# jQuery Isotope Filtering on multiple types and categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to figure out how to construct the filter selector for the jQuery Isotope plugin.

We are going to use it for a calendar/scheduler where people can filter on 5 different event types (like education, programs, tournaments) and 4 different event categories (like national, your section, all sections and sponsor).  All 5 types are on by default, also national and your section events are on by default.

So I need to write a selector that has both ANDs and ORs in it.  Not sure how to do it.
.type1.cat1 would work only for 1.  So how do I do
(.type1 OR type2 OR type3 OR type4 OR type5) AND (cat1 OR cat2 OR cat3 OR cat 4)?

So if they turn national off I will only see section events but if all the types are on, then it would be section events of all types.

UPDATE:
Looks like this actually did the trick, though not sure how efficient it actually is:
    function filterTypes(){
        var types_selected = "";

```
    $("#categories .btn_cats:checked").each( function(i,v){
        $("#types .btn_types:checked").each( function(j,w){
            if (types_selected != ""){
                types_selected += ", ";
            }
            types_selected += $(v).attr("data-filter") + $(w).attr("data-filter");
        }); 
    }); 

    console.log(types_selected);
    $("#schedule_ul").isotope({ filter: types_selected });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[isoSelective](https://github.com/simmerdesign/jquery-isoselective) might be what you're looking for as far as combining isotope filters.